# How to deobfuscate Dart stacktrace from iOS crash log

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, crash

My Flutter iOS app crashes on end-user. I have .crashpoint log, symbolicated the crashing thread and got this output:

```
Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   App                             0x000000010947a4dc get_runtimeType + 196
1   App                             0x00000001092b43a8 unnamed_dart_function_3781360 + 192
2   App                             0x0000000108f25460 unnamed_dart_function_1114580 + 464
3   App                             0x0000000108f24bc0 unnamed_dart_function_1113360 + 368
4   App                             0x0000000109157398 unnamed_dart_function_2749488 + 232
5   App                             0x000000010940ea88 unnamed_dart_function_4824204 + 1040
6   App                             0x0000000108ffd678 unnamed_dart_function_1757232 + 432
7   App                             0x0000000108ffcb88 unnamed_dart_function_1755588 + 136
8   App                             0x0000000108ffcae4 unnamed_dart_function_1755520 + 156
9   App                             0x000000010940110c unnamed_dart_function_4783800 + 52
10  App                             0x000000010940105c unnamed_dart_function_4783028 + 868
11  App                             0x0000000108e28ce4 unnamed_dart_function_332820 + 340
12  App                             0x0000000108e28b74 unnamed_dart_function_332756 + 148
13  App                             0x0000000108ddb754 unnamed_dart_function_90900 + 172
14  App                             0x0000000108ddb688 unnamed_dart_function_90832 + 96
15  App                             0x0000000108ddb608 unnamed_dart_function_90748 + 112
16  App                             0x0000000108ddb820 unnamed_dart_function_91088 + 136
17  App                             0x0000000108dc9ee0 stub 2DE0 + 220
18  Flutter                         0x000000010517bc8c dart::DartEntry::InvokeFunction(dart::Function const&, dart::Array const&, dart::Array const&, unsigned long) + 6077580 (dart_entry.cc:145)
19  Flutter                         0x0000000105274d34 Dart_InvokeClosure + 7097652 (dart_api_impl.cc:4778)
20  Flutter                         0x0000000104f8a2e8 flutter::Shell::OnAnimatorBeginFrame(fml::TimePoint, unsigned long long) + 4039400 (shell.cc:1131)
21  Flutter                         0x0000000104f713d4 std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__function::__func<flutter::Animator::AwaitVSync()::$_3, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::allocator<flutter::Animator::AwaitVSync()::$_3>, void (std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::FrameTimingsRecorder, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<flutter::FrameTimingsRecorder>>)>::operator()(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<flutter::FrameTimingsRecorder, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<flutter::FrameTimingsRecorder>>&&) + 3937236 (function.h:359)
22  Flutter                         0x0000000104f9a0fc std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__function::__func<flutter::VsyncWaiter::FireCallback(fml::TimePoint, fml::TimePoint, bool)::$_0, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::allocator<flutter::VsyncWaiter::FireCallback(fml::TimePoint, fml::TimePoint, bool)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 4104444 (function.h:359)
23  Flutter                         0x0000000104e86cdc fml::MessageLoopImpl::FlushTasks(fml::FlushType) + 2976988 (message_loop_impl.cc:128)
24  Flutter                         0x0000000104e89e80 fml::MessageLoopDarwin::OnTimerFire(__CFRunLoopTimer*, fml::MessageLoopDarwin*) + 2989696 (message_loop_darwin.mm:86)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ca89d32c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1797)
26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ca8599a8 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 940 (CFRunLoop.c:2402)
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ca7fd548 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 288 (CFRunLoop.c:2560)
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ca84afa0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1896 (CFRunLoop.c:3120)
29  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ca84feb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
30  Flutter                         0x0000000104e89f6c fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 2989932 (message_loop_darwin.mm:52)
31  Flutter                         0x0000000104e89a5c void* std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::tuple<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::unique_ptr<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct, std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::default_delete<std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::__thread_struct>>, fml::Thread::Thread(std::_LIBCPP_ABI_NAMESPACE::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>>(void*) + 2988636 (thread:295)
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000218a516cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000218a50ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)
```

App lines are most likely our own app Dart code, but for some reason there is only unnamed_dart_function_3781360 etc. Different crashes contain same unnamed_dart_function strings (with different numbers). How can get the actual Dart stack trace out of these? Apparently there are 0 matches when searching "unnamed_dart_function" from Google.

On Android, stack trace is different and on there using `flutter symbolize` worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using tool called [iXGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/ixguard) by GuardSquare to protect our app and this causes the stacktrace above. It is known issue according to GuardSquare support:

> As a temporary workaround, if you build your Flutter app without --obfuscate and --split-debug-info it should still print the correct stacktrace.